# Creating a android app in which there is bluetooth transfer of information being updated from another android application

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, data-transfer

I am creating an app for a electric car battery status. I want to create an app that will transfer data to my car battery app regarding the different parameters inside the battery. I cannot find a way to create a bluetooth connection and send a string or double values from one app to another using bluetooth. i just need the code for the following:

1. Bluetooth connection
2. Transfer of string or double values
3. Frequent updation of values

{One Raw App will send the values working like an updater of values.
while he Other will display the values. All transfer is done using bluetooth}

Comment: Both apps are running on the same device? Why use Bluetooth then?

Comment: no there are two different phones with different apps. one is used to update the values. the other is used to recieve and show the values.